# CSS Shadow get all div bottom width?

Tags: css

I want a box BOTTOM shadow to get all the div #menu width, but the shadow is letting a left and right margin... What should I change to get the full #menu bottom shadow without that margin?

```
#menu{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px #555;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6zkLngz/

thank you friends!

Comment: are you talking about left and right bottom corners?? :\

Comment: yes! @NoobEditor I want the shadow to get all div width, without that corners...

Comment: buddy, its a expected behavior....native css shadowing!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for box-shadow is: (**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)**)

```
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
```

You are setting the spread-radius to -2px. If you reset that to 0 you'll get the box-shadow on the full width.

```
#menu{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 2px 0 #555;
}
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px 0 #555;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu></div>
```

If necessary, you could then adjust the blur-radius... something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c6zkLngz/2/).

---

**Alternatively**, (and only if it's feasible) you could whack left and right white borders on the element... something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c6zkLngz/3/)

```css
#menu {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 2px -2px #555;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1.8px solid white;
  border-right: 1.8px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu></div>
```

Comment: @NoobEditor you could add extra blur, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c6zkLngz/2/)

Comment: bang on...and here i was thinking on lines of extra wrapper with overflow hidden...+1 mate!! :D